# wood plank subfloor repair and leveling

Tags: wood, subfloor

[image]

Our plank subfloor needs repair and leveling.

Could we do the following:

1. replace some of the pieces
2. add a layer of structural plywood (1/2" or 5/8") on top
3. use cement patch compound to level it
4. add finish plywood

Comment: If thine eye offends thee, pluck it out! (I'd be making a cut all the way around that room and cleaning that nasty old stuff right out. That also affords you the opportunity to level any faulty joists.)

Comment: we will replace many or all of those pieces. can cement patch compound be used on top of the wood plank directly or its better to use plywood and surface shim to level it?

Comment: That's sort of my point. Why would you go to that effort for a sub-par result when you could pop them all out and lay fresh, flat, strong, beautiful plywood in its place?

Comment: "If thine eye offends thee, pluck it out! "  @isherwood should get extra points just for that.... I agree tho. Get rid of all of it and replace it with plywood. Also, make sure that the wood beneath it doesn't need fixed too while you're at it.

Comment: No cement patch!

Answer (score 1):

I would make a cut with a circular saw set to the thickness of the boards all the way around the room, as close as the saw allows to the wall. I'd then fit 3/4" plywood inside the cut, adding framing below where necessary to support the edge well. I'd then overlay 1/2" plywood wall-to-wall, with construction adhesive between it and the old boards. Screw it all down with 2-1/2" construction screws.

If you're set on leaving the old boards in place, here's what I'd do:

1. Screw every board down tight with 3" construction screws, two per board per joist. Don't bother replacing any unless they're rotten or otherwise falling apart.
2. Grind down any severe bumps or high spots. If the boards are all down tight to the joists I wouldn't expect many.
3. Run 1/4" beads of construction adhesive perpendicular to the boards and on 6-8" intervals.
4. Set your plywood overlay and screw it down on an 8" grid using 2" construction screws, creating a laminated bond with the boards below.

Comment: thanks a lot! would it be a good idea to use a cement patch compound to level under the plywood and then screw down the plywood? would this be sturdy enough to install durock board+porcelian tiles? or would a decoupling membrane be a better option to replace durock board?

Comment: Cement patch compound has no business in a wood subfloor. As I explained, there should be no real need for that. If you have flatness issues, do what I suggested and fix the framing. Tile typically calls for at least 1-1/4" of subfloor in good condition. I think I'd want 3/4" over those boards.

Comment: Also, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know what's expected of you when you ask a question on Stack Exchange.

Comment: If the floor joists are no longer level or sturdy you'll need to either replace them or sister additional joists to them to make the floor level and solid. You won't be able to fix the floor (or install tile) if the joists under it are faulty or crooked, etc. It might just be the picture, or just me, but it looks like you have some issues with the joists....